# What is wrong with this CASE statement: it doesn't SUM?

Tags: mysql

The temperature field, INT(11), is not summing in the CASE statements:

```
SELECT storenumber as storenumber,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature <  0              THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS Under0,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN  0 AND 20 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `0To20`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `21To30`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `31To40`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `41To50`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `51To60`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `61To70`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `71To80`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `81To90`,
  SUM((CASE temperature WHEN temperature > 90              THEN SumOfTotalPrice ELSE 0 END)) AS `Over90`
FROM `reconciled`.totalsalesbystoreandtemperature 
GROUP BY storenumber
```

Here's the result of the query:
[image: Query Results]

Here's the contents of the underlying recordset:
[image: Underlying Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change all `CASE temperature WHEN ...` parts to `CASE WHEN ...`, like so:

```
CASE temperature WHEN temperature BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN
```

change to

```
CASE WHEN temperature BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN
```

Currently, `CASE` tries to compare `temperature` column to result of logic test given in `WHEN` statement. Since those are different types, you constantly get `false` and `0` in result.